# How to perform division from look up table as denominator in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following tibble:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~gene, ~celltype,
  "a",   "cel1_1",  
  "b",   "cel1_1",  
  "c",   "cel1_1",  
  "a",   "cell_2",  
  "b",   "cell_2",  
  "c",   "cell_3",  
  "d",   "cell_3"
)

df %>% group_by(celltype)
#> Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
#> Groups: celltype [3]
#> 
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>    gene celltype
#>   <chr>    <chr>
#> 1     a   cel1_1
#> 2     b   cel1_1
#> 3     c   cel1_1
#> 4     a   cell_2
#> 5     b   cell_2
#> 6     c   cell_3
#> 7     d   cell_3
```

Which I used to produce two summary. First is the overlap among gene
for every celltype pair:

```r
celltype_pair_gene_overlap <- crossprod(table(df))
celltype_pair_gene_overlap 
#>         celltype
#> celltype cel1_1 cell_2 cell_3
#>   cel1_1      3      2      1
#>   cell_2      2      2      0
#>   cell_3      1      0      2
```

Second is the gene count for every cell type

```r
celltype_gene_count <- df %>% group_by(celltype) %>% summarise(nof_genes = n())
celltype_gene_count
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   celltype nof_genes
#>      <chr>     <int>
#> 1   cel1_1         3
#> 2   cell_2         2
#> 3   cell_3         2
```

What I want to do is to divide every value in `celltype_pair_gene_overlap`
based on look up tibble in `celltype_gene_count` as the denominator.

Resulting in this table:

```r
   celltype    cel1_1        cell_2          cell_3
   cel1_1      1.00  (3/3)   0.67 (2/3)      0.33 (1/3)
   cell_2      1.00  (2/2)   1.00 (2/2)      0    (0/2)
   cell_3      0.5   (1/2)   0    (0/2)      1    (2/2)
```

How can I achieve that in base R or (preferrably) dplyr?

Comment: @akrun It's diffferent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the numeric index, based on that get the `nof_genes`, replicate it and divide

```
celltype_pair_gene_overlap/celltype_gene_count$nof_genes[
   match(row.names(celltype_pair_gene_overlap), celltype_gene_count$celltype)
        ][row(celltype_pair_gene_overlap)]
```

NOTE: This was based on the assumption that the 'celltype' are not in the same order always.  If it is of the same order, a simple division can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a straight division, as `table` and `group_by` should put the levels of celltype in the same order...

```
celltype_pair_gene_overlap / celltype_gene_count$nof_genes

        celltype
celltype cel1_1    cell_2    cell_3
  cel1_1    1.0 0.6666667 0.3333333
  cell_2    1.0 1.0000000 0.0000000
  cell_3    0.5 0.0000000 1.0000000
```